# How can I construct an instance of an immutable data type using branching logic?

Tags: c++, immutability

I am programming in C++ and trying to use immutable data types, as a way to learn something new, and also because I have been told that using immutable data types can make it easier to reason about the effects of code, because you know that once an instance is constructed it cannot be changed.

Often I want to create an instance of data using branching logic. For example:

```
int x = 0;
if (a)
{
    x = 1;
}
else
{
    if (b)
    {
        x = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        x = 3;
    }
}
DoSomething(x);
```

However, if my data type is immutable, that code will not compile, because there cannot be a copy assignment operator:

```
struct Immutable
{
public:
    const int x;

    Immutable(const int x)
    : x(x)
    {}
}

Immutable x(0);
if (a)
{
    x = Immutable(1); // Compiler error
...
```

I can think of 2 possible solutions. First, I could use the ternary operator to construct my data based on a condition:

```
Immutable x = a ? Immutable(1) : (b ? Immutable(2) : Immutable(3));
```

But this leads to complicated syntax very quickly.

Alternatively, I could use a `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Immutable> x = nullptr;
if (a)
{
    x = std::unique_ptr<Immutable>(new Immutable(1));
}
else
{
    if (b)
    {
        x = std::unique_ptr<Immutable>(new Immutable(2));
    }
    else
    {
        x = std::unique_ptr<Immutable>(new Immutable(3));
    }
}
DoSomething(*x);
```

But this seems to me like it might be negating the benefit of using immutable data in the first place.

Finally, it may be the case that what I am trying to do makes no sense, and I should just use mutable data types.

What is the proper technique to use to reap the benefits of immutability?

Comment: Why not simply hiding `const int x;` as a private member `int x;` and don't allow change through any public/protected member functions?

Comment: @tobi303 I don't want to mutate it after construction, but I want the construction to be dependent on my branching logic. Alternatively, I suppose I could mutate the constructor arguments in my branching logic and then construct an instance in a single line at the end.

Comment: Without changing the interface, the `std::uniqe_ptr<Immutable>` solution looks most straightforward IMO.

Comment: _@Ryan_ Beyond the mechanics, could you give a better example of your concrete use case please ([edit] it into your question).

Comment: @Dan Not really. But explains what I meant in my 1st comment.

Comment: sry deleted comment because it was only half-serious. I was also thinking of branching on the constructor parameters, but to be honest I have zero experience with immutables

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for your comments. Using pseudo-immutables is another good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just create your arguments as independent variables. In the case you presented:

```
int n;
if (whatever) {
    n = 0;
} else {
    n = 1;
}

Immutable x(n);
```

If you need to initialize it in one line (for example, in the initialization list of a constructor), then simply put your logic in a function.

```
Immutable foo() {
    int n;
    if (whatever) {
        n = 0;
    } else {
        n = 1;
    }

    return Immutable(n);
}

struct Thingy {
    Immutable x;
    Thingy() :x(foo()) {}
};
```

Comment: "Functions" are what immediately came to my mind too.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ? I don't understand the reference

Comment: @Martin Benjamin == Brain, Martin == Pinky. No Offence as mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

`unique_ptr` is almost appropriate, except it does a heap allocation. We can make our own <s>smart pointer</s>container class though.

```c++
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
template<class T> struct onstack {
    __attribute__((__aligned__(__alignof__(T))))
    char buffer[sizeof(T)];
    bool initialized;
    onstack() : initialized(false) {}
    ~onstack() { if (initialized) (*this)->~T(); initialized = false; }
    template<class... Args> void operator()(Args&&... args) {
        if (initialized) (*this)->~T();
        initialized = false;
        new (buffer) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        initialized = true;
    }
    operator boolean() { return initialized; }
    T& operator*() { return reinterpret_cast<T&>(buffer); }
    T* operator->() { return initialized ? &**this : nullptr; }
};
```

```c++
onstack<Immutable> x;
if (a)
    x(1);
else if (b)
    x(2);
else
    x(3);
```

This might be useful if the different branches took different arguments.

Comment: Essentially [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) (or [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) in c++17).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Nice, I didn't realize `std::optional` was coming (and why has it taken so long?). Yes, essentially that.